# $_POST JSON where object name had [ ] and http_build_query

Tags: json, curl, post

I catch JSON as $_POST (array).

```
{"invoices":{"0":{"invoice":{"fullnumber":"PROF 1\/12\/2018","semitemplatenumber":"PROF [numer]\/12\/2018","type":"proforma"}},"parameters":{"limit":"20"}},"status":{"code":"OK"}}
```

This JSON contain string "[number]". So when i try use function http_build_query() result is cutted:

```
{"invoices":{"0":{"invoice":{"fullnumber":"PROF 1\/12\/2018","semitemplatenumber":"PROF [numer]=
```

I need transfer all data via CURL fuction.

I try build own function:

```
function post_var($post_value,$data){
    foreach ($post_value AS $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $data .= $key . '=' .post_var($value, $data). '&';
        } else {
            $data .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        }
        print_r($data);
    }
    return $data;
}
$data = post_var($_POST);
$data = rtrim($data, '&');
```

but still I he'd same result. 
How to parse $_POST array into string, transfer, decode and again parce as a JSO
Thx for help.